# Visual Studio 2013, Cannot Add > ExistingProject

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As you can see, there is an error when trying to add existing project.
It happens in some solutions only, and the add **new** project works fine.

The message received is "The operation could not be completed"[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It solved.
I had to open the solution from VS 2015 then add the project.
Eventually after a while even in 2013 it works again.